# Is there a more elegenat way to create a variable dynamically in R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, linear-regression

I'm developing a R Shiny app which allows the user to investigate the simple principles of linear regression models interactively. My code runs perfectly well. However, it's not very elegant. Find the server function for illustration below (For the sake of convenience, I leave the `ui` and personal defined functions out, but let me know if you want to see them):

```
#### Make Server ####
server = function(input, output) {

#if the users presses submit:
#take the input, format it, and forward it to 'simulation' 
#which creates a dataframe(column1 = simulated response, column2 = group)
  simulate <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    group1 = as.numeric(c(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1))
    group2 = as.numeric(c(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2))
    group3 = as.numeric(c(input$n3, input$mean3, input$sd3))
    all_groups = list(group1, group2, group3)
    data = simulation(all_groups)
    })

#model a linear regression based on the simulated data, print the output
  output$model <- renderPrint({
    data = simulate()
    model = lm(response ~ group,
               contrasts = list(group = "contr.sum"),
               data = data)
    summary(model)
  })

#plot density plots for every group in one graph
#add the intercepts/coefficients returned by the linear regression to that graph
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    data = simulate()
    model = lm(response ~ group,
               contrasts = list(group = "contr.sum"),
               data = data)
    intercept = model[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]]
    intercept_g1 = model[["coefficients"]][["group1"]]
    intercept_g2 = model[["coefficients"]][["group2"]]
    ggplot(data, aes(x=response, fill=group)) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group1"), alpha=.5) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group2"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group3"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g1) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g2)
  })

#if the user presses 'reset', reset all input panels to their default value
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    shinyjs::reset("side-panel")
  })
}
```

The two main issues disturbing me are:

1. Both, `renderPlot` and `renderPrint` create the `data` variable in their first line (and `data` is also created in `eventReacitve`). Is it possible to create 'data' once as the user hits the submit button (the implementation of which is not shown here)?
2. Both, `renderPlot` and `renderPrint` compute the linear regression model. While the first needs only the output, the second needs some values that are stored in the lme variable (here the intercepts). Is it here also possible to calculate the model only once?

If you suggest ti improve the code also w.r.t to other issues, please let me know. This is just a small part of a bigger project; several options for the user will be added and an efficient and easy maintainable code will be very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should calculate your model in another `reactive` In this way you can set up your data in your `eventReactive` and create a `get_model` reactive in which you read the `data` and in your `render*` functions you use this model.

Pseudo code would be something along these lines:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## create a get_model reactive
  ## thanks to the reactive nature it will cache its values unless data changes
  get_model <- reactive({
     my_data <- req(simulate()) ## use require to make sure it is well defined
     lm(response ~ group, 
        contrasts = list(group = "contr.sum"),
        data = my_data)
  })

  output$model <- renderPrint({
    ## you could use validate(need(.)) here to make sure the model is well defined
    ## validate(need(get_model(), "Model not yet defined! Please simulate some data first!")
    summary(get_model())
  })
}
```

In this way you calculate your model only when the data changes and only once and not twice in `renderPrint`  and  `renderPlot`. The data is anyways only generated anew when the button is hit. In this way you make good use of `shiny's` builtin reactive system.

---

I just saw that you also need  `data` in your plot function, so I would simply do something like this:

```
simulate <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
   ## create data first
   group1 <- as.numeric(c(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1))
   group2 <- as.numeric(c(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2))
   group3 <- as.numeric(c(input$n3, input$mean3, input$sd3))
   all_groups <- list(group1, group2, group3)
   data <- simulation(all_groups)
   ## create model
   model <- lm(response ~ group, 
        contrasts = list(group = "contr.sum"),
        data = data)
   ## return a list with both elements
   list(data = data, model = model)
})
```

Then you can use it in `renderPrint` like this:

```r
output$model <- renderPrint({
   summary(simulate()$data))
})
```

And in render plot like this

```r
output$hist <- renderPlot({
   data  <- simulate()$data
   model <- simulate()$model
   intercept = model[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]]
   intercept_g1 = model[["coefficients"]][["group1"]]
   intercept_g2 = model[["coefficients"]][["group2"]]
   ggplot(data, aes(x=response, fill=group)) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group1"), alpha=.5) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group2"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group3"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g1) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g2)
})
```

Comment: cool, I haven't thought of combining the output of simulate in a list. That makes things simpler and faster!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this might not be most elaborate or convoluted answer (and I do not have enough reputation to simply comment), but as a general approach, I would suggest that you summarize all your steps into different functions. For example, if I see this correctly, your `renderPlot()` call only depends on `simulate()`, while the rest of the calculations are based on the data that is provided by `simulate()`. Hence, you could summarize this to

```r
plot_data <- function(data_input) {
    data = data_input
    model = lm(response ~ group,
               contrasts = list(group = "contr.sum"),
               data = data)
    intercept = model[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]]
    intercept_g1 = model[["coefficients"]][["group1"]]
    intercept_g2 = model[["coefficients"]][["group2"]]
    ggplot(data, aes(x=response, fill=group)) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group1"), alpha=.5) + 
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group2"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_density(data = subset(data, group="group3"), alpha=.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g1) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=intercept_g2)
}
```

This would reduce your call to

```
output$hist <- renderPlot({plot_data(simulate())})
```

Furthermore, writing these functions outside your shiny app also lets you test and debug them more easily in a common R environment, while you can focus on your app in the server function.